# linear fractional transformation of the complex plane that goes to the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all linear fractional transformation that maps {$z:Im(z)>0$} to {$w:|w|<1$}

I don't know anything about this.. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Find one, call it $T$. Suppose there is another. Call it $S$. Then $TS^{-1}$ maps the disc conformally to itself, hence has a very precise form. Use your knowledge of this form and the inverse of $T$ to find a general form for $S$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Bilinear Transformations](http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/mobiustranformationmod.html).

Comment: thx 4 the link.

Comment: @user114952: You are wecome.